# .htaccess throws a 500 error upon most any edits

Tags: apache, .htaccess, password-protection, errordocument

The following code **WORKS**:

```
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter the username and password"
Require valid-user
```

The following **doesn't**:

```
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter the username and password"
Require valid-user
<Directory /var/www/e>
    Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

And by doesn't, I mean it throws the server default's 500 error.

I'm doing this in attempt to have an ErrorDocument for a 403 page, but any time I specify one it's given me a 500 error. I thought originally this was probably because the 403.html document I was trying to link to was password protected, but it isn't.

The following code also throws a 500:

```
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter the username and password"
Require valid-user
ErrorDocument 403 http://google.com
```

Relevant file readout? (I think?) My apologies about being so new to this.

```
root@####:~# cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride none
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride none
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
root@#####:~#
```

I'm just looking to create a 403 document, being pointed in any direction would be extremely helpful. My apologies again about how simplistic this must seem, my google-fu just isn't strong enough to find a resource that accurately matches "creating 403 error htaccess causes 500 error"

Comment: Look in the Apache error log. There should be more details related to the 500 error there.

Comment: `<Directory>` tag isn't allowed in .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

`<Directory>` directives are only allowed in server context (i.e. httpd.cont, apache2.conf, virtual host configs, or similar server-level config files for your OS).

This makes sense when you think about it, as `.htaccess` IS in directory context already.

Check this link for more information on `Directory` directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory

I am guessing your `ErrorDocument` directive is not working because you do not have `AllowOverride FileInfo` set for the directory in your conf file. This is necessary to enable ErrorDocument and other file-level directives in the directory specified.

See this link for more information on `AllowOverride`: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Unless you have a specific reason to put the directive you have in `.htaccess`, you might consider putting them in `<Directory>` blocks in conf file and making `AllowOverride` = `none` for all directories.  This is better from a performance perspective. As teh server doesn't need to inspect every directory in a request's hierarchy to look for `.htaccess` instructions.